# How subclass reference-variable can point to superclass object

Tags: java

A subclass reference-variable cannot refer to superclass:

```
 Child c1 = new Parent();  // Error Incompatible types
```

So we are telling the compiler i known the type of object:

```
Parent p1 = new Child();
Child c1 = (Child) p1;
```

My question is how the Child-class reference variable can point to the super-class object without rising error in run time and if you use casting it changes the state of that type e.g:

```
int num = (int)6.6;  // Result = 6
```

Something must be happens when p1 object is casted to Child-class.

Comment: `new Parent()` is NEVER a `Child`, but a `p1` *can* be a `Child`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're confusing a *reference* or object with a *reference variable*, and the difference between the two is a key concept that underlies object-oriented programming principles.

Here:

```
Parent p1 = new Child();
Child c1 = (Child) p1;
```

`p1` is ***not*** a super-class object. Rather it's a super-class *variable* that refers to a child object in your code. So on the second line, your Child *variable*, `c1` is being assigned a Child object. Note that this code will be allowed by the compiler even if `p1` held a super's object, but then the JVM would throw a class cast exception when the code is run.

Comment: Thank you it gives error in runtime, there is a mistake in the code i mean was this:                                                                                                          
    Parent p1 = new Parent();
    Child c1 = (Child) p1;